# migrate on openstac from one project to another

Tags: cloud, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I was wondering if there any way migrate all the resources on openstack (Havan or grizzly) from one project to another?

I found a way to storage (using transfer-create ) and to machine i can always create an image and upload the image to the current project (although i was wonder if there is an easier way) , But i still missing a lot of resources (like network, snapshot, port...).
I think that the most difficult one will be networks because all i can think about is cheating and create the network (with the ports and subnet) on the new project.

So if any of you have any answer (partial or  full) i will be forever grateful
Thanks
Limor

Answer (score 1):

Are you migrating in the same workplace or a different location?

If the workplace is same , one few changes in the configuration files is required else you will have to do some more rework for mapping the IP addresses and corresponding grants and privileges for your services!